# WorkitemStore fetch takes too long

Tags: c#, tfs

i am trying to get a list of all bugs in a collection in TFS programmatic-ally.  But the  `tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>()` takes too long and even after 10 minutes, does not return anything. Is there an underlying issue here that i might be overlooking? There are only about 10 projects in the collection and roughly 600 work items .

```
 var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory
   .GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsnpt.someaddress.com:8080/tfs/"));

           tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

           var workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the collection from the URL, e.g. `http://tfsnpt.someaddress.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`?

Is the user allowed to read from that Collection?

Is there any proxy configuration to reach the server?

Comment: Your code snippet seems ok to me, so I would continue explore connection issues.

Comment: Yes it was indeed a network issue. The code worked fine when i tried today. Thank you.